# Directory Synchronization Error

Tags: azure, active-directory

I am currently trying to sync my on-premise Active Directory (hosted on Windows Server 2012 R2) with Azure's AD using the AD sync tool. However, I cannot get past the "Windows Azure Active Directory Credentials" step.

I have two accounts (for the sake of this post, let's call them A and B), both of which are global administrators on Azure. When I enter the credentials for account A, the sync tool insists that "The user name or password is incorrect" even though I can log onto the Azure portal with those exact credentials on my browser. It may be worth noting that account A does not require additional verification to sign on.

Account B has additional security verification and thus I created an app password for the sync tool (this feature is not present on account A since it does not require verification). Whenever I use the generated app password, I am greeted with the configuration error: "Unable to establish a connection to the authentication service. Contact Technical Support." Anything else in the password field will return "The user name or password is incorrect", leaving me to assume that the app password is valid, but my request is just not going through.

Each log-in attempt with account B and the app password has generated the following errors in my Server Manager logs:

```
System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Unable to establish a connection to the authentication service. Contact Technical Support. ---> Microsoft.Online.DirSync.Common.DirectorySyncConfigurationException: Unable to establish a connection to the authentication service. Contact Technical Support.
   at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
   at Microsoft.Online.DirSync.PowerShellAdapter.PowerShellCommand.ExecuteCommand(Command command, Boolean refreshPath)

Unable to establish a connection to the authentication service. Contact Technical Support.
Unable to establish a connection to the authentication service. Contact Technical Support. AuthIdentityToService() failed for adminwebservice.microsoftonline.com site with MBI_SSL policy. HResult:-2147186590. Contact Technical Support.  (0x80048862)
```

So far, I have tried:

- restarting my server
- re-installing the sync tool
- clearing my DNS cache
- restarting the Azure sync service
- disabling all firewalls

If anyone could help me interpret the errors or even provide me with a possible solution, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Have you collected a network trace when you reproduce the issue? That's where I would start...

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint used by Azure AD Sync (and DirSync) does not allow the use of app passwords. Only a username/password combination can be accepted and it has to be a global administrator. If you follow our guidance to create a strong password for "account B", you have essentially created the same thing as an app password.

/Andreas Kjellman
Senior Program Manager, Microsoft, Identity and Access Management, sync services